# ¿Por qué mi consulta AJAX no funciona?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function buscar_main_page() {

    var URLprotocol = window.location.protocol;
    var URLdomain = "localhost";
    var texto_main_menu = document.getElementById("buscador_main_page_input").value;

    alert(texto_main_menu);
    var parametros = {
                "texto" : texto_main_menu,
        };
    alert(parametros);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "core/models/ajax/validar_busqueda.php",
        data: parametros,

       success: function (response) {
            $("#datos_main_buscador").html(response);
        }
    });
    alert("despues");
}
```

solo llega las 2 primeras alertas, la ultima no me llega la alerta, no se por que no se ejecuta; es la primera vez k uso ajax

Comment: Probablemente hay algo incorrecto en tu php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despúes del **success** puedes poner una función **error**, ahí te darás cuenta de cuál es tu error. Quizá no llegue al **alert** porque hay un error en tu **ajax**.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "core/models/ajax/validar_busqueda.php",
    data: parametros,

   success: function (response) {
     $("#datos_main_buscador").html(response);
   },
   error: function (error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at buscar_main_page (home_main.js:9)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (?buscador_main_page=crisk:1256)

Comment: no es una función me dice

Comment: desde hace tiempo me llega eso

Comment: Asegúrate de usar bien la librería. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: va en el header o en el final del body?

Comment: En el header, creando un script.

Comment: gracias, era la version de Jquery :")